# The measure of a rectangle is zero

Tags: measure-theory

Show that the measure of a rectangle is zero if and only if the inside is empty.

Could you give me some hints what I could do??

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? Measure on what measure-space? How do you define a rectangle.

Comment: Surely this is false, what if the interior contains one point?

Comment: Show that the inside is empty **iff** at least one of the sides has zero length.

Comment: @user4894 could you explain me why it is false??

Comment: @MaryStar I might be misunderstanding. Usually in measure theory a rectangle includes its interior. Let's use the 2-dimensional plane for simplicity. The way this question is phrased, a rectangle is just the *boundary*, which is a 1D object in 2D space, having measure zero. In that case, if it also contains a point (or even some more 1-D line segments) its 2-D measure is still zero. However this is confusing, because "rectangle" typically includes its interior for purposes of measure theory. It's quite possible that I'm confused, but I'd like some clarity on what you mean by rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $(\Bbb R^2, \mathcal{M}, \mathfrak{m})$ is the Lebesgue measure space, and $R = |a,b| \times |c,d|$ (I'm using | to denote any type of interval), then: $$\mathfrak{m}R = \ell(|a,b|) \ \ell(|c,d|) = (b - a)(d - c).$$

Comment: Same counterexample as above, take the boundary of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ union a single interior point. The OP's claim is false.

Comment: @IvoTerek The direction $\Rightarrow$ is as followed: $$m(R)=0 \Rightarrow (b-a)(d-c)=0 \Rightarrow b=a \text{ or } d=c \\ \text{ that means that one side of the rectangle is } 0 \text{ so the interior is empty. }$$ Is this correct?? And the direction $\Leftarrow$ is as followed: $$\text{ The interior is empty means that } a=b \text{ or } c=d \\ \text{ Therefore, } m(R)=(b-a)(d-c)=0$$ Is this right??

Comment: Seems ok to me.

Comment: @IvoTerek Ok!!! This stands in $R^2$, right?? But does it also stand in $R^d$, where $d \geq 2$ ??

Comment: Yes, there's nothing special about $d = 2$. $${\frak m}\left(\prod_{k = 1}^d |a_k, b_k|\right) = \prod_{k = 1}^d \ell(|a_k,b_k|) = \prod_{k = 1}^d b_k - a_k.$$

Comment: @IvoTerek I see... Thanks a lot!!! :-)